# trying to avoid repeat insertion of value in table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have program which run after every 5 minutes from scheduler in which i am trying to avoid repeated insertion of values in a method.

In ‘FetchOracle’ method I am looping value pass to ‘getDo’ Method In ‘getDo’ there is also looping from there I am passing value to ‘insertSql’ method after inserting in “INFO” table . I am updating “INFOS” table after that updating in “UpdateOracle” table. My concern is that if there is two rows value in ‘getDo’ Method then insertion of value in  ‘insertSql’ method should be done only one time how to avoid that double insertion in ‘insertSql’ method if there are two rows of values in ‘getDo’ Method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            FetchOracle();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
public static void FetchOracle (object o)
        {
            string val1,val2_T, val3_T;           

            try
            {
                using (oracle connection setting)
                {
                    String sql = "select command";
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
                    da.SelectCommand = new OracleCommand(sql, con);
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        val1 = row["a"].ToString();
                        val2_T = row["b"].ToString();
                        val3_T = row["c"].ToString();
                        getDo(row["d"].ToString(), val1, val2_T, val3_T);                        
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
private static void getDo(string DoNo, string val1, string val2_T, string val3_T)
        {
            try
            {
                using (oracle conn)
                {                   
                    string L, M, N;
                    string query = "select L,SUBSTR(N,'1','10') as N,M from T_veh  where L=:L";
                    OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(query, con);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("L", DoNo);
                    OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(myCommand);
                    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        L = row["L"].ToString();
                        N = row["N"].ToString();
                        M = row["M"].ToString();
                        insertSql(L, N, M, val1, val2_T, val3_T);
                    }


                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
}
private static void insertSql(string L, string N, string M, string val1, string val2_T, string val3_T)
        {
            try
            {                
                using (sql connection)
                {
                    string query = "INSERT INTO INFO (SDO_NO.. ,USERID)";
                    query += " VALUES (@SDO_NO..,@USERID)";

                    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDO_NO", N);
                    ……..
                    con.Open();
                    int i = myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    if (i > 0)
                    {                        
                        try
                        {
                            using (sql connection)
                            {
                                string query1 = "UPDATE INFOS SET TAG=@TAG,.. where REG_NO=@REG_NO and INVOICE_NO=@INVOICE_NO";
                                SqlCommand myCommand1 = new SqlCommand(query1, con1);
                                myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TAG","N");                                            myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REG_NO", val1);
        myCommand1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@INVOICE_NO", N);
                                con1.Open();
                                int j = myCommand1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                con1.Close();
                                if (j > 0)
                                {
                                    UpdateOracle(val1, L);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {

                            throw;
                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
private static void UpdateOracle(string val1, string L)
        {
            try
            {
                using (oracle connection)
                {
                    string query = "UPDATE MST  SET P=:P where Q=:Q and L=:L";
                    OracleCommand myCommand = new OracleCommand(query, con);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("P", "S");
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("Q", val1);
                    myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("L", L);
                    con.Open();
                    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

Expected :if there is two rows value in ‘getDo’ Method then insertion of value in  ‘insertSql’ method should be done only one time .
Actual:if there is two rows value in ‘getDo’ Method then insertion of value in  ‘insertSql’ method done twice.

Answer (score 1):

So Distinct your DataTable and then iterate and insert.

```
DataView view = new DataView(table);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);

foreach (DataRow row in distinctValues.Rows)
{
    //your logic
}
```